# How to know node/entity ID from a submit handler?

Tags: forms, entities

How to know node/entity ID from a submit handler of a form created with hook_form()?

I need to make db_update() query on a single row from submit handler called by admin/structure/video/manage/% form created with Forms API.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend *not* to use extra submit handlers on node forms. Forms are not the only way that you can create a node. Modules like Feeds, Migrate, etc can create nodes programatically.

If it's a node, and you don't want to alter data that the node itself, implement [`hook_node_insert`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) and you have access to the whole `$node` object!
`$node->nid` would be the node ID if you name your function's first argument as `$node`.

If you prefer an extra submit handlers, you can access node or entity that is being created/updated in $form (I can't remember the exact key name though).

Install [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module. Then, you can see what's in the `$form` array in your submit handler like this:

```
function mymodule_extra_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
  dpm($form); // pretty-prints the entire form.
}
```

Usually `$form['#node']` is the node object, so `nid` is `$form['#node']->nid`

Comment: It is an entity not a node. There are no '#node' element in the array $form. You don't remember the exact key and I am searching of this key long time :-(

Answer (score 2):

<del>$form['build_info']['args'][0]['id']</del>

$form_state['build_info']['args'][0]->id;

Answer (score 0):

might be you are using 
$form['#submit'][] = 'custom_submit_function';

use this code:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custom_form_submit';
```

Definitely you will get `nid` on `print_r($form_state);`

e.g

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

if ($form_id == 'portfolio_node_form') {
   // $value = $form['nid']['#value'];
   $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'ita_custom_form_submit';
}

return $form;
}

function ita_custom_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
      $val = array();
    $val = $form_state['values'];
    print"<pre>";
    print_r($val);
    //exit(); // do uncomment to see form_state object
//coding
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'custom_submit_handler';
```

to add my submit handler to run after the default submit handler.

Then in my custom handler function, I found the entity ID in the $form_state variable:

```
$form_state['values']['entity']->id
```

I hope this helps someone!